# ActiveRecord Reputation System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am currently using https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system version 3.0.1 in which a source can only evaluate once. When I look into the codes there is unique validation like this

*the same source cannot evaluate the same target more than once.*

```
validates_uniqueness_of :source_id, 
                        :scope => [:reputation_name, :source_type, :target_id, :target_type]
```

But in my application the reality a source may evaluate a target more than once based on date of consuming the service. Ex. **A customer can review the same restaurant every time he dines.**

What do you recommend to customize the gem to support this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove the gem, write the functionality yourself
- Fork, make the change

  - create a Pull Request, wait until merged and released, use new version
  - release with a new name
- Remove the validation and all other required changes through monkey-patching
- Create an issue and hope somebody else resolves it or that you receive feedback from the maintainer

Now the code has not been updated since 2 years. There are 22 open issues from 2012 - 2016. This either means that it's working as expected or that it has been abandoned.

You are in a situation where you can see the "cost of free". Every library that you add to your codebase has associated costs. Even when it is free.

I for myself would write the functionality myself. But I don't know how complex your app is.

Comment: It is fairly complex though. Example, a customer can review a restaurant based on some dimensions like 'Service', 'Staff', 'Food', 'Hygiene' etc anytime he/she dines there. The customer can review the restaurant after every time he/she completes the dining...I am forking the gem and remove the unique validation to see how it works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As said: i don't know what functionality you use from the gem. The gem itself is of course more complex because it is flexible and configurable.

Comment: My solution is that I forked and removed the validation and fixed specs...and now it is working for my project. you can check it out https://github.com/meassinal/activerecord-reputation-system